# Nested While loop not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, while-loop

I am very new to Python. I just learnt about for and while loops. There was this exercise given to us to print all prime numbers from a list. I did the following

```
my = [4,5,7,16,17,35,20,37]

for i in my:
    j = 2
    while j < i:
        if i % j == 0:
            break
        j = j + 1
    else:
        print(i)
```

And this worked but since i am just learning, out of curiosity I tried to achieve the result alternatively

Instead of filtering and disallowing numbers as non prime in the `if` condition , I tried to do opposite ie evaluating numbers as prime in the `if` condition and use else to print non occurrence or prime number

```
my = [4,5,7,16,17,35,20,37]

for i in my:
    j = 2
    while j < i:
        if i % j != 0:
            print(i)
        j = j + 1
    else:
        print("Prime No not found")
```

The issue with with this code it , its prints  (i) as soon the first instance of j satisfies the if condition.
In the if statement , ideally  I want it to first complete the while loop for j and print (i) only if all of the instance of `j` satisfies (`i % j is != 0`)

With my current knowledge , I am unable to fix it. Can someone please rectify my code ?

PS: I don't want a totally different or a advanced answer, just need changes in mine itself so i can understand at my beginner level.

In short , i am basically trying to use the if condition to store prime numbers and else for non prime , Unlike my first working code where i did the opposite

Comment: I think there is an error with indentation before print

Comment: How would fixing the code differ from the first code example you give? I could come up with a version that uses `all` and a generator expression, but anything simpler is going to be essentially the same as where you started.

Comment: @Blckknght i basically wanted to use the if condition to store prime numbers and else for non prime , Unlike my first code .    i thought it might be possible

Comment: No, it's not possible. If *any* divisor exists, your number is not prime (so you can stop checking the rest). It's only when you've checked them all (or a subset, there are cleverer algorithms that test less) that you can know a value is prime.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks for the confirmation , if you can write it as an answer.  I will mark as accepted

Comment: Simple optimization: To see if N is prime You only need to check all numbers up to sqrt(N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to reverse the logic from the first version of your code. You need to run the whole inner loop before you can know the number you are testing is prime. You *might* find that it's *not* prime early (letting you quit and not test the rest of the potential divisors), but there's no instant check for primeness that you can do inside the inner loop. If there was, you wouldn't need the loop at all!

Any effort to "fix" your second code would just turn it in to the first version you started with. There *are* better prime-testing algorithms, but they're mostly a lot more complicated, and would fundamentally change the structure of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Observe the comments I implemented in the code:

```
my = [4,5,7,16,17,35,20,37]

for i in my:
    j = 2
    while j < i:
        if i % j == 0: # As long as there's a single division that results in 0 remainder, the number is not prime
            break
        j = j + 1
    else:
        print(i)
```

Since you don't have a `break` statement inside the `while` loop below, the `else` statement will always be initiated. That is the whole point of an `while` `else` statement. So you need to add a `break` somewhere.

```
my = [4,5,7,16,17,35,20,37]

for i in my:
    j = 2
    while j < i:
        if i % j != 0: # If a number is prime, all the cases will result in non-zero remainder, so many numbers will be print out
            print(i)
        j = j + 1
    else:
        print("Prime No not found")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but the output of the second code is same what i originally had

Comment: @Sachin Yes, I pointed out the error, but hadn't changed it.

Comment: oops my bad , i also edited it in question , indentation probably got a bit messed during pasting

Answer (score -2):

```
my = [4,5,7,16,17,35,20,37]

for i in my:
    j = 2
    while j < i:
        if i % j != 0:
          print(i)
        break # you need to put the break out of if statement,so it will go to the next number to test, Hope this help
    else:
        print("Prime No not found")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering , although for some reason it prints 35 as well

Comment: This code prints all numbers that are not even. The inner loop only runs one iteration, so you only test with `j=2`.